# What is wrong with my jquery post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit

```
$("#login").click(function() {
   var mydata = $("#loginform").serialize();

   $.post("http://events.rate-mate.com:5000/auth", {
     data: mydata
   }, function(response) {
     $("#result").html(response);

   }, "json");
});
```

It does not send any parameters, and there is no response.

Comment: are you doing a CROSS domain request ?

Comment: what you wana do exactly?

Comment: I want to post two parameters (username, password) to a foreign server that i do not know, and get back a json token. I have set my localhost parameters correctly, becouse the server only responds if it thinks i am on the same domain. I am building an app for a hotel service by the way.

Comment: remove the `,"json"` param and try .

Comment: @SJWimmer87 Look at your developer console. It will tell you what is not working. Add an error handler to you r Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

See the below example for submitting a form through `ajax post`

```js
//callback handler for form submit
$("#loginform").submit(function(e) {
  var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
  var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
  $.ajax({
    url: formURL,
    type: "POST",
    data: postData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      //data: return data from server
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //if fails      
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
  e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});

$("#loginform").submit(); //Submit  the FORM
```

```html
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="sample_url.php" method="POST">
  First Name:
  <input type="text" name="fname" value="" />
  <br/>Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="lname" value="" />
  <br/>Email :
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
  <br/>
</form>
```